# How to create lag feature in pandas in this case?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this (with more columns):

```
date,Sector,Value1,Value2
14/03/22,Medical,86,64
14/03/22,Medical,464,99
14/03/22,Industry,22,35
14/03/22,Services,555,843
15/03/22,Services,111,533
15/03/22,Industry,222,169
15/03/22,Medical,672,937
15/03/22,Medical,5534,825
```

I have created some features like this:

```
sectorGroup = df.groupby(["date","Sector"])["Value1","Value2"].mean().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df,sectorGroup,on=["date","Sector"],how="left",suffixes=["","_bySector"])

dateGroupGroup = df.groupby(["date"])["Value1","Value2"].mean().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df,dateGroupGroup,on=["date"],how="left",suffixes=["","_byDate"])
```

Now my new df looks like this:

```
date,Sector,Value1,Value2,Value1_bySector,Value2_bySector,Value1_byDate,Value2_byDate
14/03/22,Medical,86,64,275.0,81.5,281.75,260.25
14/03/22,Medical,464,99,275.0,81.5,281.75,260.25
14/03/22,Industry,22,35,22.0,35.0,281.75,260.25
14/03/22,Services,555,843,555.0,843.0,281.75,260.25
15/03/22,Services,111,533,111.0,533.0,1634.75,616.0
15/03/22,Industry,222,169,222.0,169.0,1634.75,616.0
15/03/22,Medical,672,937,3103.0,881.0,1634.75,616.0
15/03/22,Medical,5534,825,3103.0,881.0,1634.75,616.0
```

Now, I want to create lag features for  `Value1_bySector,Value2_bySector,Value1_byDate,Value2_byDate`

For example, a new column named `Value1_by_Date_lag1` and `Value1_bySector_lag1`.

And this new column will look like this:

```
date,Sector,Value1_by_Date_lag1,Value1_bySector_lag1
15/03/22,Services,281.75,555.0
15/03/22,Industry,281.75,22.0
15/03/22,Medical,281.75,275.0
15/03/22,Medical,281.75,275.0
```

Basically in `Value1_by_Date_lag1`, the date "15/03" will contain the value "281.75" which is for the date "14/03" (lag of 1 shift).

Basically in `Value1_bySector_lag1`, the date "15/03" and Sector "Medical" will contain the value "275.0", which is the value for "14/03" and "Medical" rows.

I hope, the question is clear and gave you all the details.

Comment: Should your lag always be by 1 calendar day, or is it sometimes a few days (e.g. perhaps there are days such as weekends with no data)?

Comment: It dont include weekend data or holiday data @Stuart Sorry for late reply

Comment: But if you have a solution @Stuart, I can map the dates to be continous and then remap to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a lagged date variable by shifting the date column, and then merge again with `dateGroupGroup` and `sectorGroup` using the lagged date instead of the actual date.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""date,Sector,Value1,Value2
14/03/22,Medical,86,64
14/03/22,Medical,464,99
14/03/22,Industry,22,35
14/03/22,Services,555,843
15/03/22,Services,111,533
15/03/22,Industry,222,169
15/03/22,Medical,672,937
15/03/22,Medical,5534,825"""))

# Add a lagged date variable
lagged = df.groupby("date")["date"].first().shift()
df = df.join(lagged, on="date", rsuffix="_lag")

# Create date and sector groups and merge them into df, as you already do
sectorGroup = df.groupby(["date","Sector"])[["Value1","Value2"]].mean().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df,sectorGroup,on=["date","Sector"],how="left",suffixes=["","_bySector"])
dateGroupGroup = df.groupby("date")[["Value1","Value2"]].mean().reset_index()
df = pd.merge(df, dateGroupGroup, on="date",how="left", suffixes=["","_byDate"])

# Merge again, this time matching the lagged date in df to the actual date in sectorGroup and dateGroupGroup
df = pd.merge(df, sectorGroup, left_on=["date_lag", "Sector"], right_on=["date", "Sector"], how="left", suffixes=["", "_by_sector_lag"])
df = pd.merge(df, dateGroupGroup, left_on="date_lag", right_on="date", how="left", suffixes=["", "_by_date_lag"])

# Drop the extra unnecessary columns that have been created in the merge
df = df.drop(columns=['date_by_date_lag', 'date_by_sector_lag'])
```

This assumes the data is sorted by date - if not you will have to sort  before generating the lagged date. It will work whether or not all the dates are consecutive.

Comment: wow, this is simple solution. Thats really smart of you.

Answer (score 0):

I found 1 inefficient solution (slow and memory intensive).

Lag of "date" group

```
cols =  ["Value1_byDate","Value2_byDate"]
temp = df[["date"]+cols]
temp = temp.drop_duplicates()
for i in range(10):
    temp.date = temp.date.shift(-1-i)
    df = pd.merge(df,temp,on="date",how="left",suffixes=["","_lag"+str(i+1)])
```

Lag of "date" and "Sector" group

```
cols =  ["Value1_bySector","Value2_bySector"]
temp = df[["date","Sector"]+cols]
temp = temp.drop_duplicates()
for i in range(10):
    temp[["Value1_bySector","Value2_bySector"]] = temp.groupby("Sector")["Value1_bySector","Value2_bySector"].shift(1+1)
    df = pd.merge(df,temp,on=["date","Sector"],how="left",suffixes=["","_lag"+str(i+1)])
```

Is there a more simple solution?

Comment: Edit: this seems incorrect solution, created same sector rows of each date